# no Component Definition Wizard in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-indigo, buckminster

i'm going to add service to my OSGI project and follow [the tutorial](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Developing_Plug-Ins_-_IFormFactory_%28ZK_Webui%29) to add "Component Definition" using eclipse wizard. so i navigate to menu "new->plug-in development->Component Definition" but i can't find there.

i'm using eclipse indigo and buckminster 3.7

i tried using eclipse juno and buckminster 4.2 still got the same problem.

so, is my buckminster installation wrong or something that i miss? thx for your help.

[screenshot here](http://i1029.photobucket.com/albums/y358/uthadehikaru/componentdefinition_zps4820834e.png)

**I GOT THE ANSWER**

> the problem is related to my eclipse. i'm using Eclipse Java Developer
>   rather than for EE Developer. when i reinstall the eclipse using for
>   EE Developer and install buckminster, i found the Component Definition
>   Wizard.

Maybe someone need this info. thx

Comment: You are looking in `New > Other...` rather than `New > Project...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the [Plugin Development Environment](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/).  You don't actually nee the EE Developer version for this, you can install just this feature.